# What does '|' in {{ services|pprint|safe }} mean in django?

Tags: django, templates

I know that in views.py file:

```
def index(request):
    person= {'firstname': 'Craig', 'lastname': 'Daniels'}
    weather= "sunny"
    context= {
        'person': person,
        'weather': weather,
        }

    return render(request, 'Articles/greeting.html', context)
```

Then we can do in greetings.html:

```
<h1>Hi {{ person.firstname }} {{ person.lastname }}</h1>

<h1>Today it is {{ weather }}</h1>
```

where {{ person.firstname }} is a variable defined in context.

But what does '|' mean?

```
{{ services|pprint|safe }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They are called [built in tags/filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/)**

Basically it takes the variable passed to it by the view and processes it in a certain way. The | indicates that the data to the left is to be passed to the right, which is a function which returns a value.

[pprint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#pprint) is a wrapper for the pprint in Python, which is a function to print data structures nicely to the console.

[safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) has to do with HTML escaping. Essentially, it is telling Django that the content needs no further processing before it is output onto the template.